# How to save current SQL Server user to custom table through c# client?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I use С# Express with Entity Framework. And not very good in SQL Server scripting.

So, I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE DataTable
(
  Id                INT              NOT NULL  ,
  Value             VARCHAR(20)          NULL  ,
  Author            ???????????      NOT NULL  ,
  CreateTime        DATETIME         NOT NULL  ,  
  CONSTRAINT PK_DataTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (num ASC) 
  ON [PRIMARY] 
)
```

Tell me please, how to write current Server user as author of data commit to my table.
Users enter through a local network in SQL Serve authorization mode.
It should be pretty transparently for c# programmer, and it should be handle on server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a great place for a trigger. [Database triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) are often used for logging operations such as the one you're describing. In the trigger simply include the [current user](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/27/sql-server-2005-get-current-user-get-logged-in-user/) in your insert data.

There is a [complete sample here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0560__Trigger/Referencecurrentusernameintrigger.htm).

Comment: Thanks for help. I used this script (see below).

Answer (score 2):

you can make it `varchar(100)` with a default of `SUSER_SNAME()` for insert, for an update use an `update trigger` or pass in `SUSER_SNAME()` from your front end.

`SUSER_SNAME()` will work for both windows and sql logins

Answer (score 0):

I used this script

```
    CREATE TRIGGER Author
    ON DataTable
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
    AS
    DECLARE
    @Value nvarchar(max),
    @CreateTime datetime

    SET @Value = (SELECT Value FROM inserted)
    SET @CreateTime = (SELECT CreateTime FROM inserted)

    INSERT INTO [DataTable]
               ([Value]
               ,[Author]
               ,[CreateTime])
        VALUES (@Value
               ,USER_ID()
               ,@CreateTime)
    GO
```